# Why management interface is always vlan interface and not just physical interface?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, management

In Cisco switches/routers or any other vendor, why the management interface is always a vlan IP interface and why not just fa 0/1 or fa 0/2 ip interface. What's the reason behind vlan ip interface for management purpose?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the model of device.  Some of them have dedicated physical management interfaces.  Others just use a vlan SVI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Also, besides what John K. wrote, if the switch can do layer-3, you *can* use a routed interface:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no switchport
 ip address 10.11.12.13 255.255.255.252
 no shutdown
!
```

If you are running layer-2 to a router, then the only network you have between the switch and the rest of the network is either an address on one of the VLANs between the router and switch, or, as John K. says, some Cisco switches have a physical management interface that must be connected to somewhere else on the network.